# facebook app login doesn't work in facebook canvas

Tags: facebook, canvas, authentication

My app needs facebook login.
everything works fine on my website, but inside facebook canvas, login doesn't work..
App checks if user is loged in.. if not, it redirects:

```
  $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array( 'scope' => 'photo_upload', 'user_likes', ));
  header ("Location: $login_url");
```

How shoud I redirect user to dialog/oauth??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Canvas app are contained inside iframe, you should use javascript and redirect top frame to your login url like this

`top.location = '<?=$login_url?>';`

Comment: but after oauth it redirects to my website, I'm mising something. I need to redirect it to canvas url apps.facebook.com/myapp

Comment: Check to documentation of Facebook::getLoginUrl function here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/ you can pass redirect_uri in your array so you can point your app canvas as redirect uri.

Comment: I fixed it! Thank you once again :)